# Will it harm my ranking to resubmit links to my site after permanently redirecting to a new domain name?

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect

Ok so i have **site1.com** and **site2.com**, and i want to move from **1** to **2** with "Change of adress" 301 redirects .. etc. Now i submited **site1.com** in a lot of websites/blogs, so i have a decent amount of link building.

Now when all the page rank juice transfers from 1 to 2 is there ok to resubmit once again **site2.com** for more link juice? I mean to resubmit it in blogs, web directories, bookmarks ... etc? Isn't that a violation of google's guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, all of the links juice will not transfer from site 1 to site 2. Some of it will be lost when the 301 redirect is made. It's not much but it does happen.

And you can't double up on link juice. so if someone links to site 1 and links to site 2 it's just like linking to the same site twice. It only counts once. So you can promote your site normally and if it gets linked to in the same page twice it won't be a problem. It will just count once.

Comment: that's disappointing, but what would you rather do? Start your work from scratch (to do a better job) or redirect 1 to 2, because to be onest, i have dropped from 70,80 seo visits per day to 10,20, because, i think, i never updated my website for 1 year ...

Comment: It depends, why do you want to move to site2.com?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can submit links to search engines. It won't be a problem.  You need to make sure you keep `site1.com`.  If it expires and you don't renew it, you may lose the human clicks that may come from referrals.